# Codeigniter merge form fields into database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, model

I have two form fields on my view page, a date input (with a date selector popup) and a time input.

When passing these values into the model, is it possible to merge them together so they will both go into a single database field with a type of Timestamp? e.g 12/12/2012 + 14:20 and saved to the db as 2012/12/12 14:20:00

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you just need simple string concatenation? http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to join them together, and you're fine with the combined field being a string, you could just concatenate.

```
$date = $this->input->post('date');
$time = $this->input->post('time');

$timestamp = "$date "."$time";
```

You would also need to create a field in your DB model for this new timestamp field.

Comment: Brilliant, thats spot on! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should do some sort of validation of the date as well to be sure if fits your db format

something like below:

```
$date = new DateTime($this->input->post("date");
$time = new DateTime($this->input->post("time");

$datetime = $date->format("Y-m-d") . $time->format("H:i:s");
```

Then use the $datetime variable in your model to be inserted.